# Filter JSON using more than one option

Tags: javascript, ionic3

I have a JSON:

```
location_filter = [{ title: "My Library", type: "library"},
      { title: "My Parking", type: "parking" },
      { title: "My Info", type: "info" }]
```

And I have a Multiple drop-down with three options: "info", "parking", "library".

I am already sending the value that I want to filter that can be one or more than one.

I know how to use the filter with just one item.

My question is: How can I use with more than one item?

```
splitFilter(array){
    var arr = array.split(',');
    return arr;
  }


filter(selection) {

    let stringSplit = this.splitFilter(selection.toString());

        this.location_filter = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.locations));

        this.location_filter = this.location_filter.filter((item) => {
            return item.type === selection;
        });

    this.loadMap(this.location_filter);
}
```

I am already splitting the string with the function splitFilter();

Maybe a loop?

Comment: As a note, this is _not_  *JSON* - it's just a JavaScript Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```
this.location_filter = this.location_filter.filter(({ type }) => selection.includes(type));
```

Or with ES5 take [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and check if not `-1` for a not found item.

```
this.location_filter = this.location_filter.filter((item) => {
    return selection.indexOf(item.type) !== -1;
});
```

Comment: I would like to say thank you for your answer. The first options is working like a charm! Thank you and have a great day.